# PHP Crop image square black photo result

Tags: php, ios

I have an iOS app that uploads a photo to my server via base64.

I upload the image normally to a temporary location and then with PHP I want to crop it square and move it to another location.

The photo is cropping perfectly and also is uploaded correctly to the server, but the new photo (square) is black and I couldn't found a solution why.

PHP Code:

```
// Check if file was upload successfully
                if (file_exists($temporaryPath)) {
                    // Rsize and reduce photo size
                    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($temporaryPath);
                    $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($temporaryPath);
                    if ($width > $height) {
                        $y = 0;
                        $x = ($width - $height)/2;
                        $smallestSide = $height;
                    } else {
                        $x = 0;
                        $y = ($height - $width)/2;
                        $smallestSide = $width;
                    }
                    $thumbSize = 1080;
                    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbSize, $thumbSize);
                    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $myImage, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbSize, $thumbSize, $smallestSide, $smallestSide);
                    imagejpeg($thumb, $imagePath, 100);

                    // Check if new image exists
                    if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
                        // Upload success
                        $response = array(
                            "id"=>"NULL",
                            "msg"=>"success"
                        );
                        echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$response));    
                        exit();
                    } else {
                        // Failed to resize photo
                        $response = array(
                            "id"=>"NULL",
                            "msg"=>"error"
                        );
                        echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$response));    
                        exit();
                    }
                }else{
                    // Upload failed
                    $response = array(
                        "id"=>"NULL",
                        "msg"=>"upload_failed"
                    );
                    echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$response));    
                    exit(); 
                }
```

The variable **$temporaryPath** is the path to the current photo uploaded temporary.

What should I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you actually checked that the image as uploaded (i.e. the one at `$temporaryPath`) is a valid picture? Have you tried reading it and then immediately saving it again under a different file name (to check if it's correctly read by `imagecreatefromjpeg`? Is it actually a JPEG? Have you checked that the computed values of `width`, `height`, `x`, `y` and `smallestSide` are correct? Is the picture actually larger than 1080x1080?

Comment: It is correct, when it comes from iOS is a PNG and on the temporary I save it as .jpg. And yes, in this example is larger than 1080x1080.

Comment: You mean you just rename it as a .jpg but it's actually a png? I believe imagecreatefromjpeg expects an actual jpeg. Have you tested its return value?

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: `if ($myImage)`

Comment: Yes, you are right. It goes in the else. So should I change it with imagecreatefrompng ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jcaron I solved the problem. I saved the image as a PNG as it comes from iOS and I replace the imagecreatefromjpeg with imagecreatefrompng.